# Flutter: get message on Push notifications even if the app is closed using local notification

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I built an application for Android and iOS using Flutter, using local notifications, Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), and SharedPreferences to handle push notifications with news and calls to action (CTAs) about my product.

I have a section in the app where I display the latest received notifications, similar to a notification center. However, when the app is closed or in the background and the user receives a notification, they need to click on the notification for the app to be invoked, and the message to be saved and displayed in the notification center.

How can I overcome this limitation and make the app obtain the push content and save it in the notification center while it's in the background or closed, without the user clicking on the push notification?

I thought my method FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler) would solve this and should be called in this situation, but it's only invoked when I click on the notification.

My current code is something like on flutter:

```
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

      .
      .
      .
        //flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin initializationSettings
      .
      .
      .


      /// Open app receive
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {
        if (message != null) {
          // save and processMessage
        }
      });

      /// Background app click
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {
        if (message != null) {
          // save and processMessage
        }
      });

      /// Background closed app click
      FirebaseMessaging.instance
          .getInitialMessage()
          .then((RemoteMessage? message) {
        if (message != null) {
             // save and processMessage
          );
        }
      });

      IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
        backgroundMessagePort.sendPort,
        backgroundMessageIsolateName,
      );

      backgroundMessagePort.listen(backgroundMessagePortHandler);
```

and my firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler method is:

```
static Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(
      RemoteMessage message) async {

     .
     .
     .
      /// some IsolateNameServer configs whit aport and isolate name and solateNameServer lookupPortByName
     .
     .
     .


    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final List<String> items = prefs.getStringList('notification') ??
        List.empty(growable: true);

    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;

    items.addI( //string processing logic with message information here )

    prefs.setStringList('notification', items);


}
```

My swift code on AppDelage.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import flutter_local_notifications
.
.
.

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {


    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
      
      
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
.
.
.
```

How can I work around this limitation and make the app obtain the content of the push notification and save it to the notification center while in the background or closed, without the user having to click on the push, so that it is saved in the notification center and displayed when the user opens the app?

Comment: The app can't get the content of the notification. You will need to store the data in some other place, such as a Firestore collection, that your app can query

Comment: To do this on the client wouldn't I have to have access to the msg content in the same way? or do you suggest that I save it via the backend? because I believe it is not possible, the service is not accessible for me to change.

Comment: I am suggesting you access it from the backend. Push notifications are not a guaranteed way of delivering data to your app. They are a way of delivering notifications to a user

Comment: I understand maybe not the best designer but is it impossible on IOS? because on android it's working and the backend is inaccessible for me to change for now.

Comment: It is impossible on iOS.